# same program not running on a different server

Tags: php

Im facing a strange problem.. iv written some codes on sending mails using google smtp, yahoo smtp, and aol smtp in php. its working fine. but when im trying to run the same codes on a different server and domain it is giving me the following error:

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

any solutions??

Comment: Can that server see the SMTP host via the command line (ping, ftp, telnet etc.)?

Comment: Any more infos? Network connection and DNS name resolution working? What's the PHP version, server software and version, PHP configuration details, and so on... Crystal balls are quite expensive nowadays...

Comment: Open a command prompt (you don't say what OS though) and type "ping servername"

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are not allowed to connect to port 25. Check with the hosting company which SMTP server to use for outgoing mail.

Comment: They may have blocked ANY outgoing ports. It's standard practice to only let out controlled traffic from a webhosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
//$myid=$_REQUEST['myid'];
//$mypass=$_REQUEST['mypass'];
//$msg=$_REQUEST['msg'];
define('GUSER', 'ss@ss.com'); // Gmail username
define('GPWD', 'pass'); // Gmail password
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.aol.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    //$mail->AddAttachment('upload/logo.png', 'logo.png'); 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
    $mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
    //$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('test.html'));

    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
    // initialize reader object
    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

    // read spreadsheet data
    $excel->read('Book1.xls');      
    // iterate over spreadsheet cells and print as HTML table
    $x=1;
    while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
      $y=1;
      while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
        $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';


smtpmailer( $cell, 'ss@ss.com', 'name', 'Subject', 'trying the aol');
        $y++;
     }  
      $x++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You should have edited your question rather than posting an answer